# Looping in projekktor with Safari not working

Tags: javascript, projekktor

I'm using the `projekktor` player and I have some logic that will trigger the player to play:

`player.setPlay();` when another song is complete. This works flawlessly on Chrome and Firefox, but on Safari, if I switch to another tab, it doesn't work until I switch back to the tab I'm on. This is for Safari on the Desktop on a Mac.

The relevant code is:

```
function loopSong(){
    var idSong = player.getItemIdSong();
    $timeout(function(){
        player.setActiveItem(idSong);
        player.setPlay();
    }, 100);    
};
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does Safari completely stop any playback once you switch to an other tab or does just you loop hack not work properly?

If the latter did you try to set the player config option [loop to "true"](http://www.projekktor.com/docs/configuration#loop_booleanfalse)?

I´m not 100% sure what you´re trying to achieve. But also the built in [playlist functionality](http://www.projekktor.com/docs/playlists) might help.